# How to write "&&" in XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

How to I write `&&` in XML? I want to use it for a button. I want to use it like this:

```
android:layout_below="@id/textview && @id/anothertextview"
```

**What I'm trying to is**

I've a fragment with several tabs, and some of these tabs have a Textview-Textview-Button (under each other), and some of them only have Textview-Button. The fragments with only a Textview-Buttons are fine but the ones with 2 Textviews aren't. The button appears on the second `Textview` and not below it. 
Is there a way to tell it stay below the last widget? If it's Text1-Text2-Button, then below Text2 if it's Text1-Button then just below Text1 etc.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#006400">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/handling"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/stilling"
        android:layout_below="@id/handling"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/arabisk"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_below="@id/stilling"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/stilling"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=">"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/start"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                  />

                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="||"
                    android:id="@+id/stop"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: & replace with &amp;

Comment: @NarendraBaratam but this is not supported by the layout system.

Comment: `android:layout_below` can have only 1 view, you can't `and` it, you need to build your layout in that way, make use of other options like (`android:layout_above`) use it with `anothertextview` for example, to get to the result you need

Comment: try to modify your layout design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your xml as below. Replace RelativeLayout with LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#006400">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/handling"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/stilling"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/arabisk"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=">"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:id="@+id/start"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:text="||"
                        android:id="@+id/stop"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```